# Python Errno 2 with Windows 10

Tags: python, powershell

I am trying to run a basic hello world python program with python 2.7.5 in PowerShell (Windows 10). I created the file helloworld.py and can see the file in my current directory - however, when I try to run that file in the current directory, I get an errno 2 message that the file cannot be found:

[image: screenshot of PowerShell]

My path values appear to be set correctly for both user and system variables - I have no issue launching python in PowerShell:

[image: screenshot of path values]

I have also confirmed that python is the default open with program for .py files and that the file is not hidden and not read only.

Any idea what might be causing this error?

Comment: Try `python .\helloworld.py`

Comment: Hey Mark - I just gave that a try and I get the same errno 2 result.

Comment: Try ./helloworld.py as well, read that somewhere

Comment: Thanks, Mark - I still got the same result running with ./. I ended up copying my file and underlying folder structure from Windows\System32 to a new folder in C: and now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up copying my file and underlying folder structure from the original Windows\System32 location to a new folder in C: and now it's working.

Comment: Permissions then I guess. Was your powershell console run as admin?